# How to get access token by grant password?

Tags: php, wordpress, oauth-2.0

I get response "Trying to get property 'access_token' of non-object"

I need to use Oauth2 protocol to connect to my web.

I follow everything that i found but i get some result that i don't understand.

First of all.

the environment is localhost for testing purpose. before, i setup in live. and the wordpress is the latest 5.2.1

1. I install wordpress to my web hosting.
2. I install Oauth2 plugins to my wordpres from official wordpress github.
3. I register application from my wordpress.
4. i get the client id and client secret. I set the callback url to localhost

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init( 'https://localhost/oauth2/token' );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    'client_id' => 'dpaxxoptvane',
    'client_secret' => 'FxOPFrNKCiVJqrD7bnMpume3CL98PfsJFUa7qDWK1XVPars3',
    'grant_type' => 'password',
    'username' => 'admin',
    'password' => 'admin',
) );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$auth = curl_exec( $curl );
$auth = json_decode($auth);
$access_key = $auth->access_token;

echo $access_key
?>
```

Comment: Hi. Can you please do `var_dump($auth);` right after `curl_exec`? This will give us raw response from your HTTP request. You should also do `var_dump(curl_error($curl));` which will show all errors from the HTTP request. Please add them here, thanks

Comment: @DamianDziaduch Curl return error **string(48) "SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate" **. But, I solve it with giving ignore ssl option `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`. after all still same error in the end. _Trying to get property 'access_token' of non-object_

Comment: OK, please comment out the `$auth = json_decode($auth);` and 
`$access_key = $auth->access_token;`. After that please do `var_dump($auth);` and check what is the value of `$auth`

Comment: @DamianDziaduch It returns _bool(false)_.

Comment: So something is wrong with your Request. `curl_exec` returns `FALSE` only on failure

Comment: I follow this tutorial. in the example. it url wordpress hosting. but my condition i host wordpress in my own web hosting. is it the problem is url that to call token? thsi the url https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/oauth2/. I just change the domain from _https://public-api.wordpress.com/oauth2/token_ to _localhost_